# gcloud app deploy is failing with Failed to create cloud build: Permission denied on 'locations/xyz' (or it may not exist)

Tags: python-3.x, google-app-engine, deployment

I have a 2.x python app and some 3.x python app which are running on google app engine.

Recently, I had updated the 2.x app without any issue. Now, when I'm trying to deploy an update for a 3.x python app, I'm getting an error "Error Response: [7] Failed to create cloud build: Permission denied on"

```
Services to deploy:

descriptor:                  [C:\Users\artha\Documents\gae billApp\CbicNtfnAndAutoMailer\app.yaml]
source:                      [C:\Users\artha\Documents\gae billApp\CbicNtfnAndAutoMailer]
target project:              [cbicntfnandautomailer]
target service:              [default]
target version:              [1]
target url:                  [https://cbicntfnandautomailer.appspot.com]
target service account:      [App Engine default service account]


Do you want to continue (Y/n)?  Y

Beginning deployment of service [default]...
#============================================================#
#= Uploading 0 files to Google Cloud Storage                =#
#============================================================#
File upload done.
Updating service [default]...failed.
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [7] Failed to create cloud build: Permission denied on 'locations/asia-south1' (or it may not exist)..
```

Previously, I did not face any issue.

gcloud app describe shows me

```
authDomain: gmail.com
codeBucket: staging.cbicntfnandautomailer.appspot.com
databaseType: CLOUD_DATASTORE_COMPATIBILITY
defaultBucket: cbicntfnandautomailer.appspot.com
defaultHostname: cbicntfnandautomailer.appspot.com
featureSettings:
  splitHealthChecks: true
  useContainerOptimizedOs: true
gcrDomain: asia.gcr.io
id: cbicntfnandautomailer
locationId: asia-south1
name: apps/cbicntfnandautomailer
serviceAccount: cbicntfnandautomailer@appspot.gserviceaccount.com
servingStatus: SERVING
```

I have also tried disabling and re-enabling cloud build, but to no avail...

Can you please advice how to resolve the issue, thanks!!!

EDIT: As a workaround, created a seperate project and deployed there to resolve the issue, but the root cause still remains unknown!!

Comment: Have you double-checked that the account you're using to deploy your app has the Cloud Build Editor (`roles/cloudbuild.builds.editor`) role as pointed in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/troubleshooting#cloud-build-failed)?

Also, this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59329322/13171940) points out other required roles needed to deploy an app to App Engine.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you reached the limit of build-triggers allowed per region:
[Cloud build limits](https://cloud.google.com/build/quotas)

Comment: I have checked but found that quota is still okay, haven't reached even 10% of the same over 7 days per Google cloud platform stats page under IAM & Admin.